# Button handlers not working in custom MessageBox class

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a custom login form for a program that is invoked similar to a messagebox, returning a DialogResult to show whether the login was successful. There are three buttons, each returning a different DialogResult. (The code for actually checking the login data is not implemented yet.) However, only the Cancel button actually fires the appropriate Event, the other buttons do nothing.

```
Public Class LoginBox
    Inherits Form
    Private WithEvents btnLogin As New Button With {.Text = "Login", .Size = New Size(80, 25), .Location = New Point(230, 90), .BackColor = Color.Silver}
    Private WithEvents btnCancel As New Button With {.Text = "Cancel", .Size = New Size(80, 25), .Location = New Point(230, 120), .BackColor = Color.Silver}
    Private WithEvents btnReadOnly As New Button With {.Text = "Open in" & vbCrLf & "readonly" & vbCrLf & "mode", .Size = New Size(80, 55), .Location = New Point(130, 90), .BackColor = Color.Silver}
    Private WithEvents tbNaam As New TextBox With {.Size = New Size(180, 20), .BackColor = Color.Silver, .Location = New Point(130, 20)}
    Private WithEvents tbWachtwoord As New TextBox With {.Size = New Size(180, 20), .BackColor = Color.Silver, .Location = New Point(130, 55)}
    Private lblNaam As New Label With {.Text = "Inlognaam:", .ForeColor = Color.Silver, .Location = New Point(65, 23)}
    Private lblWachtwoord As New Label With {.Text = "Wachtwoord:", .ForeColor = Color.Silver, .Location = New Point(53, 58)}
    Private Shared WaitForButton As New System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(False, Threading.EventResetMode.ManualReset)
    Private Shared antwoord As DialogResult

    Private Sub New()
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
        ControlBox = False
        Text = "Inlog IC agenda"
        AcceptButton = btnLogin
        CancelButton = btnCancel
        Size = New Size(350, 205)
        BackColor = Color.DimGray
        Controls.Add(btnLogin)
        Controls.Add(btnCancel)
        Controls.Add(btnReadOnly)
        Controls.Add(tbNaam)
        Controls.Add(tbWachtwoord)
        Controls.Add(lblNaam)
        Controls.Add(lblWachtwoord)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Shared Function Show(ByVal ShowReadOnlyButton As Boolean) As DialogResult
        Dim X As New LoginBox
        If Not ShowReadOnlyButton Then
            X.btnReadOnly.Visible = False
            X.Size = New Size(350, 180)
            X.btnCancel.Location = New Point(130, 90)
        End If
        X.CenterToParent()
        X.ShowDialog()
        WaitForButton.WaitOne()
        Return antwoord
    End Function

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        'TODO: check login data, if incorrect, show error message

        antwoord = DialogResult.OK
        WaitForButton.Set()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        antwoord = DialogResult.Cancel
        WaitForButton.Set()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReadOnly_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnReadOnly.Click
        antwoord = DialogResult.Ignore
        WaitForButton.Set()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Testing shows the Cancel button working as expected. The other two buttons fail to raise the appropriate event, even though (in my eyes) they are coded in exactly the same way.

Comment: Add some breakpoints at each line of your `btnLogin_Click` and let us know if when you presses it goes through it or not etc.

Comment: It goes through btnLogin_Click and changes "antwoord" to the appropriate value, but nothing happens afterwards: Show() doesn't continue running, which is does if Cancel is clicked.

In fact, it turns out the same happens if I remove the entire EventWaitHandle: The Cancel button handles as normal, the other buttons still don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button handlers are working, but the form is not closed. The reason is that you miss a line in event handlers.

DialogResult = antwoord

So, your event handlers should look similar like shown in the code below.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    'TODO: check login data, if incorrect, show error message

    antwoord = DialogResult.OK
    DialogResult = antwoord
    WaitForButton.Set()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    antwoord = DialogResult.Cancel
    DialogResult = antwoord
    WaitForButton.Set()
End Sub

Private Sub btnReadOnly_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReadOnly.Click
    antwoord = DialogResult.Ignore
    DialogResult = antwoord
    WaitForButton.Set()
End Sub
```

"Cancel" is treated like DialogResult.None, so you had an impression that "Cancel" only works correctly.

Comment: Great, that explains it. It works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Incidentally, by having the Show() function return X.DialogResult, the entire antwoord variable became unneccesary.